# How do I fix this for loop that takes a value in one column to change one in another?

Tags: r, for-loop

It's been a while since I've touched for loops. I am simply trying to check if the value in the LocationID column is 1, and if so, set the value in the corresponding row in RegionID to 4. It should run through every value in the LocationID column.

```
for (i in 1:length(df$LocationID)) {
  if (df_7$LocationID == 1) {
    df_7$RegionID = 4
  }
}
```

From my understanding, the code I've come up with here just checks the first value ~44000 times (the length of the dataset) and then sets every value of RegionID to 4.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to specify the index `i` to subset the value.  In the OP's code, the `if` condition is checking the whole column 'LocationID' and `if` is not vectorized, so it expects a single TRUE/FALSE i.e a vector of `length` 1

```
for (i in seq_along(df_7$LocationID)) {
  if(df_7$LocationID[i] == 1) {
    df_7$RegionID[i] <- 4
   }
  }
```

---

In `R`, we can vectorize this easily

```
df_7$RegionID[df_7$LocationID == 1] <- 4
```

_
Or with `ifelse`

```
df_7$RegionID <- with(df_7, ifelse(LocationID == 1, 4, RegionID))
```

---

Or another option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df_7 <- df_7 %>%
            mutate(RegionID = case_when(LocationID == 1 ~ 4, TRUE ~ RegionID))
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_7)[LocationID == 1, Region_ID := 4]
```

Comment: within the for loop, probably you need `df_7$RegionID[i] <- 4`? not sure though.

Comment: @Onyambu thank you for finding that.  Appreciate it